# How to get the month of a date with two digits in SQL-92?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql-92

I have a date format cell in my table, of which I need to extract the month in two digits. This means that `6-4-2021` should return `04`. The main problem is that this needs to be in the syntax of SQL-92. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Praytell, what database supports ANSI 92 syntax?  You should tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: It's not actually a database, but I am using Information Design Tool of SAP, and that uses this syntax unfortunately when using multiple databases. Therefore it's not really about a database, but only about the syntax.

Comment: `substring('0' + substring(<column> from position('-' in <column>) + 1 for 2) from 3 - position(substring('0' + <column> from position('-' in <column>) + 1 for 2) for 2)`

Comment: Honestly I don't even remember which is the proper concatenation operator. I think that gets you fairly close though.

Comment: @shawnt00: that's `||` in standard SQL and pretty much every DBMS uses it (with one and a half notable exceptions of the "usual suspects")

Comment: @shawnt00: its concat(x,y). Thank you for your reply. Unfortuantely position() is not supported.

Comment: Look for index or instr or find... Btw the above is horribly messed up but I'll leave it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**SQL-92**

```
substring(
    '0' || substring(<column> from position('-' in <column>) + 1 for 3)
    from position(
        '-' in 
        '0' || substring(<column> from position('-' in <column>) + 1 for 3)
    ) - 2
    for 2
)
```

I had wondered if you're were really looking for ODBC functions. If so then `locate()` would be the equivalent for `position()`, noting that the argument syntax just uses comma separators. `replace()` would then also be available for an alternate approach.

Looking at some reference material for your tool I would translate it this way though it does appears that there's even a `dayOfMonth()` function that might make this all even simpler.

**SAP BusinessObjects SQL for multisource-enabled universes**

```
substring(
    '0' || substring(<column>, pos('-', <column>) + 1, 3),
    pos('-',
        '0' || substring(<column>, pos('-', <column>) + 1, 3)
    ) - 2,
    2
)
```

https://help.sap.com/doc/4667b9486e041014910aba7db0e91070/4.2.4/en-US/sbo42sp4_info_design_tool_en.pdf

See it in action with PostgreSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/72962

Comment: Unfortunately the SAP solution is not working, but your suggestion and the documentation you sent helped me in getting inspired for a solution myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Verified as valid SQL-2016 syntax, using https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/.

Answer (score 0):

**SAP BusinessObjects SQL for multisource-enabled universes**

```
substring(concat('0', toString(month(<date>))), length(concat('0', toString(month(<date>))))-1, 2)
```

I put a 0 in front of my month number converted to a string, and took the last two digits of the string.